# ArcGIS Time Series Plot

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time, chart

I have a point dataset wih 911 calls for one year, including a column with the date (day) when the call was made.

I would like to create a graphic that shows in which month how many calls were made, to analyze the temporal variation. I add a picture to illustrate the way the result should look like.

[image]

Can this be done in ArcGIS and if yes how? How do the data have to be prepared, is it necessary to add a column indicating the month and can this be done automated (as there are a lot of features present)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done in ArcGIS. The following is the link to the top of the graph section on online ArcGIS 10.2 help.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/What_are_graphs_in_ArcGIS/003300000001000000/  If you are using a different version of ArcGIS, you can simply replace the 10.2 in the URL with your version (that usually works).

Comment: How do I have to prepare the data? 
I have the Point Feature class, each Feature indicating one occurence of the phenomenon and a date column. I already made a month column in order that the number of Features per month can be displayed, but how?

Comment: You need to give it a try and post another question with your results, showing where you are stuck.